How to Login to a Website that is using an Angular ng-model form class
I am trying to use VBA to login to a website that is local to my network (http://192.168.0.160/wespjs/index.html#/login).  I'd like to navigate to the website on my own, and then use a simple command button to fill in the username and password fields, and login.
Here is what the Chrome inspection shows, can someone help point me in the right direction?
<form class="form-horizontal form-signin ng-pristine ng-valid" name="loginForm">
                <!-- <input class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Host" ng-model="host"/> -->
                <!-- <input class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Port" ng-model="port"/> -->
                <!-- <br/> -->
                <input class="form-control input-lg ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched" placeholder="" ng-model="id" autofocus="" style="">
                <input class="form-control input-lg ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched" placeholder="" ng-model="pass" type="password" style="">
                <div ng-show="loginfailmsg!==''" class="ng-hide">
                    <i class="small error-color ng-binding"></i>
                </div>
                
                <select class="form-control input-lg ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty" ng-style="styles_btncolor" ng-model="languages.current" ng-options=" key as value for (key, value) in languages.available"><option label="English" value="string:en_US" selected="selected">English</option><option label="中國" value="string:zh_CN">中國</option><option label="日本語" value="string:ja_JP">日本語</option><option label="한국어" value="string:ko_KR">한국어</option></select>
                <br>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" ng-disabled="!isValidRequest()" ng-click="login()" translate="" disabled="disabled"><span class="ng-scope">Login</span></button>
            </form>

I've researched and tried code to no avail, It seems that I don't have the right syntax to actually fill in the web form.  Inspecting in Chrome, I see the following, but honestly I have no idea how to go from here.  I have tried using IE.Document.getElementById("id").Value = username, but it just hangs.
